# How to format Facebook/Twitter dates (from the JSON feed) in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

For my iPhone application...

I am looking for a way to format the Facebook `created_time` JSON property value.

`"created_time": "2010-12-01T21:35:43+0000"`

I am also looking for a way to format the Twitter date.

`"created_at": "Wed Dec 01 17:08:03 +0000 2010"`

I wish to change both to be in the format of `Thu Nov 18, 2010 06:48 AM`, or something similar.  I have had no luck using `NSDateFormatter`.

How can i format these dates from Facebook and Twitter using Objective-C into the format i desire?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

here is what i have working for Twitter:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    //Wed Dec 01 17:08:03 +0000 2010
    [df setDateFormat:@"eee MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:[[tweets objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: TWITTER_CREATED_AT_JSON_KEY]];
    [df setDateFormat:@"eee MMM dd yyyy"];
    NSString *dateStr = [df stringFromDate:date];
```

where `tweets` is an `NSMutableArray` filled with `NSDictionary` objects, `storyIndex` being the row int value (in the tableview), and `TWITTER_CREATED_AT_JSON_KEY` being a constant `NSString` with value `created_at`. use the dateStr wherever you wish to display the date

and Facebook:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    //2010-12-01T21:35:43+0000  
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"];
    NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:[[facebook objectForKey:FACEBOOK_POST_CREATED_TIME_JSON_KEY] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@""]];
    [df setDateFormat:@"eee MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm"];
    NSString *dateStr = [df stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: correction for the Facebook format:
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"];
This format solves two problems - 
1. take note of the capital MM (months), instead of mm
2. no need to replace T with empty string when calling dateFromString later

Comment: For those who are not using the American or British locale this doesn't work. You have to set the locale of the dateformatter to: [dateForm setLocale: [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];

Comment: Another correction: "ZZZZ" outputs "GMT-0000" while "ZZ" gives you just "-0000"

Answer (score 10):

I give you the solution to parse Facebook api date time:

```
parser = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[parser setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[parser setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[parser setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"];
```

Enjoy !

eBuildy, french Web Agency

Answer (score 4):

[@binnyb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4336651/2085743) is perfect for Objective-C; for those looking to do the same thing using Swift, here's a translated version of his answer:

**For the Twitter Date:**

```
    var df = NSDateFormatter()
    //Wed Dec 01 17:08:03 +0000 2010
    df.dateFormat = "eee MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ yyyy"
    var date = df.dateFromString(twitterDateString)
    df.dateFormat = "eee MMM dd yyyy"
    var dateStr = df.stringFromDate(date!)
```

**For the Facebook Date:**

```
    var df = NSDateFormatter()
    //Wed Dec 01 17:08:03 +0000 2010
    df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"
    var date = df.dateFromString(facebookDateString)
    df.dateFormat = "eee MMM dd yyyy"
    var dateStr = df.stringFromDate(date!)
```

where `twitterDateString` and `facebookDateString` are the date strings obtained from their respective APIs.

Answer (score 3):

```
"created_at" = "Sat Apr 05 06:31:57 +0000 2014";
```

Following Method Return How many time before twit aris.

```
-(NSString*)retrivePostTime:(NSString*)postDate{

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [df setDateFormat:@"eee MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ yyyy"];
    NSDate *userPostDate = [df dateFromString:postDate];


    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:userPostDate];

    NSTimeInterval theTimeInterval = distanceBetweenDates;

    // Get the system calendar
    NSCalendar *sysCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    // Create the NSDates
    NSDate *date1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSDate *date2 = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:theTimeInterval sinceDate:date1];

    // Get conversion to months, days, hours, minutes
    unsigned int unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

    NSDateComponents *conversionInfo = [sysCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date1  toDate:date2  options:0];

    NSString *returnDate;
    if ([conversionInfo month] > 0) {
        returnDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ldmth ago",(long)[conversionInfo month]];
    }else if ([conversionInfo day] > 0){
        returnDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ldd ago",(long)[conversionInfo day]];
    }else if ([conversionInfo hour]>0){
        returnDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ldh ago",(long)[conversionInfo hour]];
    }else if ([conversionInfo minute]>0){
        returnDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ldm ago",(long)[conversionInfo minute]];
    }else{
        returnDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lds ago",(long)[conversionInfo second]];
    }
    return returnDate;
}
```

May this help lot.

**Translated to Swift 2**

```
func retrivePostTime(postDate: String) -> String {
    let df: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "eee MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ yyyy"

    let userPostdate: NSDate = df.dateFromString(postDate)!
    let currentDate: NSDate = NSDate()
    let distanceBetweenDates: NSTimeInterval = currentDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(userPostdate)
    let theTimeInterval: NSTimeInterval = distanceBetweenDates
    let sysCalendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let date1: NSDate = NSDate()
    let date2: NSDate = NSDate(timeInterval: theTimeInterval, sinceDate: date1)
    let conversionInfo: NSDateComponents = sysCalendar.components([.Hour, .Minute, .Day, .Month, .Second], fromDate: date1, toDate: date2, options: [])

    var returnDate: String = ""
    if conversionInfo.month > 0 { returnDate = String(format: "%ldmth", conversionInfo.month) }
    else if conversionInfo.day > 0 { returnDate = String(format: "%ldd", conversionInfo.day) }
    else if conversionInfo.hour > 0 { returnDate = String(format: "%ldh", conversionInfo.hour) }
    else if conversionInfo.minute > 0 { returnDate = String(format: "%ldm", conversionInfo.minute) }
    else if conversionInfo.second > 0 { returnDate = String(format: "%lds", conversionInfo.second) }

    return returnDate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something similar to this should do the first one for you. i would double check against the docs, as i may have capitalised the wrong letters.

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-ddThh:mm:ss z"];
NSDate *date=[NSDateFormatter dateFromString:twitterDate];
```

Comment: this did not work.  also i believe what you entered is a little wrong: `NSDateFormatter` should be replaced with `dateFormatter`.  when i use this code to format the above Twitter date, i get a null string using `NSString *d = [dateFormatter stringWithDate:date];`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *yourInputFBdate = @"2010-12-02T20:12:06+0000";
NSString *fbDate = [yourInputFBdate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@" "];
fbDate = [fbDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" +"];
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithString:fbDate];

/// do something with date ...

[date release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to complicate things a bit, the JSON response of the [Twitter Search API](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search) currently returns a date format (inherited from Summize) which is something like:

```
@"Sun, 05 Jun 2011 12:25:47 +0000"
```

To convert this to NSDate, use:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"eee, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Sun, 05 Jun 2011 12:25:47 +0000"];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Translated to Swift 2** (Nimit Parekh answer)

```
func retrivePostTime(postDate: String) -> String {
    let df: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "eee MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ yyyy"

    let userPostdate: NSDate = df.dateFromString(postDate)!
    let currentDate: NSDate = NSDate()
    let distanceBetweenDates: NSTimeInterval = currentDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(userPostdate)
    let theTimeInterval: NSTimeInterval = distanceBetweenDates
    let sysCalendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let date1: NSDate = NSDate()
    let date2: NSDate = NSDate(timeInterval: theTimeInterval, sinceDate: date1)
    let conversionInfo: NSDateComponents = sysCalendar.components([.Hour, .Minute, .Day, .Month, .Second], fromDate: date1, toDate: date2, options: [])

    var returnDate: String = ""
    if conversionInfo.month > 0 { returnDate = String(format: "%ldmth", conversionInfo.month) }
    else if conversionInfo.day > 0 { returnDate = String(format: "%ldd", conversionInfo.day) }
    else if conversionInfo.hour > 0 { returnDate = String(format: "%ldh", conversionInfo.hour) }
    else if conversionInfo.minute > 0 { returnDate = String(format: "%ldm", conversionInfo.minute) }
    else if conversionInfo.second > 0 { returnDate = String(format: "%lds", conversionInfo.second) }

    return returnDate
}
```